# error splitting video into images using opencv in python: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Tags: python, opencv

I'm try to implement a function that split a video then save the frames unfiltered and grayScaled but I'm encountering this error in the end of every run:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

I guess it has something to do with trying to save an extra frame that does not exist but I'm not sure how to fix it.

here is the relevant code:

```
def saveFramesUnfiltered():
vid = cv2.VideoCapture("Maxwell Cat.mp4")  # getting the video
currentFrame = 0  # counter for frames (to organize them by order)

while True:
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break  # end loop when finished
    success, frame = vid.read()
    cv2.imshow("Output", frame)
    cv2.imwrite("./framesBefore/frame" + str(currentFrame) + '.jpg', frame)  # save unfiltered frame to folder and show the video (using the frames)
    im = Image.fromarray(rgb_to_gray(frame))
    im.save("./framesAfter/frame" + str(currentFrame) + '.jpg')
    currentFrame = currentFrame + 1

vid.release()
```

Comment: why did you not check `if not success: break`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the condition for breaking. The condition look like this:

```
success, frame = vid.read()
if not success or cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break # end loop when finished
```